# why is this storyboard not instantiating?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've worked in iOS completely programmatically and I've worked completely with IB, but I'm trying to mix the two for the first time and I'm getting confused.  I'm writing a tabbed application.  In my app delegate, I used to have the following code:

```
//...Code setting view controllers for various tab items and then this...

GHSettingsViewController *svc = [[GHSettingsViewController alloc] init];
svc.tabBarItem.title = @"Settings";
svc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"20-gear-2.png"];
[tabItems addObject:svc];
```

And that was fine.

Then I created a view controller via storyboard in IB and added a bunch of UI elements to it, giving it the following settings:

[image]

Now my code reads:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
GHSettingsViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settings"];
svc.tabBarItem.title = @"Settings";
svc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"20-gear-2.png"];
[tabItems addObject:svc];
```

The application launches fine, but when I press the tab to go to the settings screen, I get the following message:

[image]

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** Here's a fuller version of the code from the app delegate in `didFinishLaunching`:
    {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

```
NSMutableArray *tabItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

GHHaikuViewController *hvc = [[GHHaikuViewController alloc] init];
hvc.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";
hvc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"53-house.png"];
[tabItems addObject:hvc];

GHComposeViewController *cvc = [[GHComposeViewController alloc] init];
cvc.tabBarItem.title = @"Compose";
cvc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"216-compose.png"];
[tabItems addObject:cvc];

GHWebViewController *wvc = [[GHWebViewController alloc] init];
wvc.tabBarItem.title = @"Buy";
wvc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"80-shopping-cart.png"];
[tabItems addObject:wvc];

GHFeedback *fvc = [[GHFeedback alloc] init];
fvc.tabBarItem.title = @"Feedback";
fvc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"18-envelope.png"];
[tabItems addObject:fvc];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
//UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard.storyboard" bundle:nil]; //Using this instead causes the application to crash on launching.
GHSettingsViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settings"]; 
//GHSettingsViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]; //Using this instead of the line above causes the same error.
svc.tabBarItem.title = @"Settings";
svc.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"20-gear-2.png"];
[tabItems addObject:svc];

GHTabBarController *tbc = [[GHTabBarController alloc] init];
tbc.viewControllers = tabItems;
self.window.rootViewController = tbc;

return YES;
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the stack trace of the signal.

Comment: Did you check wether it's the correct storyboard?

Comment: Are you using a tab segue?  If so, you shouldn't be instantiating a new view controller, you should be using the `prepareForSegue` method.  You can refer to it with `GHSettingsViewController *svc = (GHSettingsViewController*)[segue destinationViewController]`;

Comment: rob, I'm afraid I don't know how to find that.  If you let me know I'll add it to the question right away. Lukas, the storyboard is named Storyboard.storyboard and it's the only storyboard I have.  Aaron, I'm not confident I understand what a tab segue is but just tried your substitution and got an "use of undeclared identifier: segue" error, so I assume I'm not using one.

Comment: I've edited my code to show a fuller version of didFinishLaunching.

Comment: Try logging both storyboard and svc in that last bit of code to make sure neither is nil.

Comment: <UIStoryboard: 0x9f87940>, <GHSettingsViewController: 0x9f8a030>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using this new `UIViewController` inside of a `UITabBarController`. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, create the new `UIStoryboard` as you were. Then create a `UIViewController` instance with

```
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Then, just add `viewController` to the `viewControllers` array of your `UITabBarController`.

I'm not sure what `tabItems` is for, but you need to be adding your view controllers to your tab bar's `viewControllers` array.

**UPDATE:** From our discussion in chat, there was an extra IBOutlet referenced in the Storyboard that wasn't actually hooked up and was causing the crash. Hitting the "Continue" button in the debug navigator gave us some extra information and led to the issue.

Comment: Hmm.  I just tried this and got the same error.  I've edited my code to show a fuller version of didFinishLaunching.

Comment: Out of curiosity...which version of iOS are you supporting?

Comment: Hm, usually you'll see that crash if you support iOS 5 and try to use Auto Layout. Do you know how to set an Exception Breakpoint?

Comment: I believe I do.  Or, rather, I know how to set a breakpoint--the blue arrow on the left side of the screen.  If an exception breakpoint is different, then, alas, I don't.

Comment: No worries! Go to the Breakpoint Navigator in the left pane (the icon looks like a breakpoint, or hit CMD+6). At the bottom, hit the '+' and select 'Add exception breakpoint'. Just hit 'Done' on the popover that appears. Run your app again and tap the new tab item. You should now see exactly what is throwing the exception.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23177/discussion-between-joel-derfner-and-jmstone)